# getFeeForMessage: Index out of Bounds

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api, python

I have a versioned message and when I query the RPC API method `getFeeForMessage` it returns "invalid transaction message: index out of bounds", but I do know it is a correctly encoded message.

For example:

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '
    {
      "id":1,
      "jsonrpc":"2.0",
      "method":"getFeeForMessage",
      "params":[
        "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"]
    }
'
```

returns:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32602,
        "message": "invalid transaction message: index out of bounds"
    },
    "id": "1"
}
```

But you could check is just fine as you can simulate it here: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector?signatures=%255B%25221111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111%2522%255D&message=AQAIEVbE%252FmUkVVSQD1LI9myS78r35TmTbJTscmmbmmoTc3J6TKGpWF2gBglZ7L7W6uq0yAe9oZKd7e43JrGBx5%252BhMT2HLuZGPt%252BtpTBc6U2ISPaNFsy7dpkbeel7qnCDJRGsnsPF%252BRSZSIga5F3INXZyciXuYEY0YyeIiVQirzH0UKTzxmr5TXI9s7UOJknq0HYQyS16nI2dIkHNzwyGUmhzmj3ctsR95gY60V6VYn2jwi0Pa%252Bm2ItuFyC7WJ9ydC%252FITCuEjJgvnj%252FcHbCbaVW%252BmoMmjDEf6ulnPZ5O3mfv8bbfh%252FnCbve40Uy1SVPMRHmixB5Xlo%252BG5xtCZ14W%252FswEfXnYFBk8aU8tdLUHU0PtMv5Jk7D%252FPZ7IG7xSpCw9u6FjZNQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbmnG6tlQqq%252Flrzt6rPk%252FdKp1%252B4TRhSjtmAgWE8OnTjyMd%252FNmHWtKjvOdvFNA7q2MPL4LRQmYQOgmPYcltYewc4yXJY9OJInxuz0QKRSODYMLWhOZ2v8QhASOe9jb6fhZAwZGb%252BUhFzL%252F7K26csOb57yM5bvF9xJrLEObOkAAAAAEedUt7b9rxezQnYRTSjSupZdQQ7Nv0CskZQu1hENZXAbd9uHXZaGT2cvhRs7reawctIXtX1s3kTqM9YV%252B%252FwCpDgNoX46QkFPkWBIcZvWnau3HcGqhHIL4qpUqjyt4eanVgl%252BCwB3iGIrchGDyrs%252F74Gz1QmGMRzHx7vceTBrJbQMNAAUCwFwVAAwGAAcACwkPAA4PDwAHEA8AAwcGAQgEAgUKI%252BUXy5d6460qAAEAAAACEQCAw8kBAAAAADUPPIK%252FAAAABQAA

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, but I've had issues with this call before, typically because I forgot to include a blockhash in the message.

Be sure that your message has a blockhash before calling `getFeeForMessage`!